# How to print state population information using API requests python

Tags: python

So I found this api http://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/ where I am trying to return all of the populations data for each state across the US but I can't seem to get the keys to be working correctly, currently I have this. My API key which is 606f9a154ca7b41d0a17e0fd00b1f413a0c230ca, but I am not sure how to put that into my python code

```
Input:
import requests# needs requests functions to call API
import pprint # pretty print
popQuery = requests.get('http://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/').json()
pprint.pprint(popQuery)


returns: {'@context': 'https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/catalog.jsonld',
     '@id': 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population.json',
     '@type': 'dcat:Catalog',
     'conformsTo': 'https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema',
     'dataset': [{'@type': 'dcat:Dataset',
                  'c_dataset': ['pep', 'population'],
                  'c_documentationLink': 'https://www.census.gov/developer/',
                  'c_examplesLink': 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/examples.json',
                  'c_geographyLink': 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/geography.json',
                  'c_groupsLink': 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/groups.json',
                  'c_isAggregate': True,
                  'c_isAvailable': True,
                  'c_valuesLink': 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/values.json',
                  'c_variablesLink': 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population/variables.json',
                  'c_vintage': 2019,
                  'contactPoint': {'fn': 'Coordination, Dissemination, and '
                                         'Outreach Branch',
                                   'hasEmail': 'mailto:POP.PEP.API.list@census.gov'},

 Input:
popQuery.keys()


returns: dict_keys(['@context', '@id', '@type', 'conformsTo', 'describedBy', 'dataset'])
```

## then when I try to get the population data

```
Input:
popQuery["dataset"]["population"].keys()
```

returns:  in 
----> 1 popQuery["dataset"]["population"].keys()

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: My bad on the formatting

Comment: `popQuery['dataset']` is a list and you can access only by integers or slices eg: `popQuery['dataset'][0].keys()`